# Adjust UITableViewCell Height with insertRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a table, in which, when a user taps on a cell, a detail cell drops down right below it. I have figured out how to use `insertRowAtIndexPath` to achieve this, however the detail cell has a row height taller than that of the normal cells. I have tried `heightForRowAtIndexPath` but that only appears to be called upon the initial loading of the view (or using `reloadData`). However, I don't want the detail cell to be added to the data for the table view, which eliminates `reloadData` as a possibility, and therefore `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. I do have a custom `UITableViewCell` subclassed as `ItemDetailCell`. I thought this might load the specified row height from the associated cell in the storyboard but that does not appear to work. This is how I tried in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (indexPath.row == _detailCellIndexPath.row && _detailCellIndexPath) {
    NSLog(@"detailCell");

    ItemDetailCell *detailCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DetailCellIdentifier forIndexPath:_detailCellIndexPath];

    //customize cell

    return detailCell;
}
else {
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //customize cell

    return cell;
}
```

I do get the return of the `NSLog(@"detailCell")` in the console, so I know it is getting called, but it still doesn't adjust the cell height.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` is also called after

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Is there any reason why you don't want to add the cell to your backing collection? The easiest solution would be to add a particular item to your table view backing array and, after that, make a call to `insertRowAtIndexPath` inside a `beginUpdates` `endUpdates` block. This will trigger the standard delegate/data source table view methods (`heightForRowAtIndexPath` included), so you could return a different size according to the concrete UITableViewCell class (`ItemDetailCell` or `CustomCell`).

Comment: Since the detail cell is my version of the detail view in the Master-Detail template, it is only temporary and not a permanent addition to the table, therefore I don't want it in the backing data as I would have to remove it constantly. It is something I want to avoid if I can.

Comment: @MusicMathTech reloadData doesn't play well with animations. If the user has a way to explicitly insert/remove rows (by tapping a cell, for example), the recommended way is put the insertion/deletion code inside a beginUpdates endUpdates animation block.